# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings even with exclusions

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, spring-boot, slf4j

I'm deploying application on Jenkins and I'm getting [Multiple bindings error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxw7N.png)

I've already tried adding exclusions to my pom. Then I ran maven *dependency:tree* command to trace if any other dependency is using logback and there is no reference to that. Here are my logs after running this command [logs](http://hastebin.com/itidofabep.rb). The wierd thing is that on my local machine the application builds and starts successfully. This is my latest pom.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module>my-first-module</module>
    <module>my-second-module</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <springboot.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.192</h2.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <jwt.version>0.6.0</jwt.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.security>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--spring-boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JWT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--common-module-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.soft.pgs</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--mapper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--HSQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--H2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have even tried stupid things like adding exclusions to every dependency in every pom and still no changes.

```
           <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

I tried also this exclusions:

```
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion> 
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
              <exclusion> 
                  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
```

And even that two combined. I don't know what other options could be, if someone hase any idea, I would appreciate that, thanks.

Added also exclusions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661189/spring-postgresql-multiple-slf4j-bindings) and still no changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring + PostgreSQL > Multiple SLF4J bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661189/spring-postgresql-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

Comment: It appears that the **slf4j-simple** dependency of PostgreSQL is the culprit here. Rather than trying to exclude logback, I think you should exclude slf4j-simple from com.soft.pgs:common. The answer I linked to in my previous comment mentions exactly the same.

Comment: I noticed that you changed your question and mentioned that the exclusions from the linked answer does not work. Can you post your current pom.xml now and show your updated mvn dependency:tree as well?

Comment: For starters I would cleanup your pom, then do `mvn dependency:tree` and see which dependency pulls in the cullprit instead of randomly excluding things

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but it started to happen when I added the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`, and after making the `mvn dependency:tree` I figure out they had also the `slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar`. Then I added the exclusion to it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

struggled several hours to resolve this error, which I was getting when running a JUnitTest for a RestController from IntelliJ.
I've tried a lot of exclude combinations in gradle,
and based on @Guilherme Alencar response, here's what worked for me:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    validateSpec.set(true)
    inputSpec.set("$rootDir/myproj/src/main/resources/api/api.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated/$generator")
    modelPackage.set("com.fanduel.loyalty.gateway.generated.models")
    apiPackage.set("com.fanduel.loyalty.gateway.generated.controllers")
    configOptions.set(
            mapOf(
                    "dateLibrary" to "java8",
                    "useTags" to "true",
                    "interfaceOnly" to "true"
            )
    )
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude(group = "slf4j-simple", module = "slf4j-simple")
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    exclude(module = "slf4j-simple")
}
```